# Position of mouse and element width differs in IE and Chrome (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am trying to detect if mouse is hovering over some element with Javascript by using mouse coordinates and element position (note that I'm not able to use hover event). For that I use this function:

```
var rect = $('.rectangle'),
    rectLeft = rect.offset().left,
    rectTop  = rect.offset().top,
    rectRight = rect.offset().left + rect.width(),
    rectBottom = rect.offset().top + rect.height();


if (rectLeft < e.pageX
    && rectRight > e.pageX
    && rectTop < e.pageY
    && rectBottom > e.pageY) {
    // in
}
else {
    // out
}
```

While it works flawlessly in Chrome, I have some issues in IE11 (didn't try lower versions), where detection is not exact - the right border of element and pageX position of mouse differs. You can see the behavior in this snippet:

http://codepen.io/Jarino/pen/qdywGv

When you go with the mouse into the area from right border, the area doesn't turn green immediatley, but after some more pixels.

Thanks for any advice.

**EDIT**

This seems to be the problem specific to only my machine, which it's pretty weird. I tried this on another company computer and it works, also as [Infira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1307641/infira) commented, it works on his enviroment too.

Comment: It works in IE10 though, actually i tried in IE11 also, worked there also. 
What OS you are using?

Comment: Windows 8, works also in Firefox

Comment: wont $("#idofthelement").hover(function(){}); work??

Comment: As I said, I'm not able to use hover event

Comment: Pleas confirm you OS, i used Vmware Fusin to test on Windows 10 IE 11 and Windows 7 IE 10, in both os it worked fine for me.